# Java: Override behaviour through association

Tags: java, dry, code-structure

I have several `Field` entities, and `Controller`s associated with them this way: `(Field,Generic_Controller <--> Specific_Controller)`. I want to implement association of each `Specific_Controller` with corresponding `Field` and `Generic_Controller` in Java. How can I accomplish this? Better in compile time.

EDIT: Here is pseudo-code of a task (maybe it would be clearer):

```
given X:Class and C:ServiceFor[X]
  where C:ServiceFor[X] means:
    C has method M with args(x:X) returning Any

goal:
get C:ServiceFor[X]
  where C and X are given. // X is Field class or instance
that:
  if there exits explicitly defined (C1 as ServiceFor[X]) and (C1 is child of C)
    return C1 // ==Specific_Controller
  otherwise:
    return C  // ==Generic_Controller
```

<s>Currently, I have implementation but its not DRY: I should keep synchronized the controller classes with `getController` body.</s> <sub>It was one of possible ways, probably leading away from problem (see first version of question, if curious).</sub>

```java
import javax.swing.*;

interface Field 
{
  Object getValue();
  /** Obtain name of field for internal usage
   */
  String getName(); 
  void setValue<T>(T value) throws InvalidValueException;
  boolean isValid<T>(T value);
  Controller getController(Class<?> genericController);
}

interface Controller {}

interface UIController extends Controller {
  /** Return GUI widget responsible to manipulating value inside FormField 
   *  instance
   * (Control logic uses setValue() ) */
  JComponent getInputControl();
}

interface UrlEncoder extends Controller {
  /** Obtain value encoded for transmition through Web.
   *
   * some fields used privately in code are cut out inside this method
   */
  String getURLEncodedValue(); 
}

class CommonUIController implements UIController { ... }

//-- MyField with specific implementations of controllers
class MyField 
    implements Field, UIController, UrlEncoder 
{
  // here methods overriden
}

//-- usage (i do it every time)
MyField mf;
UIController uiController;
if(mf instanceof UIController)
  uiController = (UIController)mf;
} else { // use default impl.
  uiController = new CommonUIController(mf);
}
```

And I wish to keep `Field`, `Controller` and declared relation between them separate from each other. Just like that C++ can do:

```cpp
//-- common.hpp
template<class _Controller, class _Field>
struct overriden_controller:
    public _Controller
{
  typedef _Controller controller_type;
  typedef _Controller type;
  typedef _Field      field_type;
};

struct UrlEncoder{};
struct UIController {};


//-- MyField.hpp
// Field knows nothing about controllers
struct MyField {};

// !! Here comes association
template<>
struct overriden_controller<UIController, MyField>
{
   // Overriden behavior 
};

template<>
struct overriden_controller<UrlEncoder, MyField>
{
   // Overriden behavior 
};

//-- And then use associated value
auto controller = new field_controller<UIController, MyField>::type();
```

What can you suggest here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me a bit contrived to fetch an instance of a class by passing an interface as parameter, unless you fill in the method with some bitecode weaving, but ...

Using a bit of convention over configuration, you implement something like this:

```
public class AbstractField {

    public Controller getController(Class clazz){
        String name = clazz.getSimpleName();

        String pack = clazz.getPackage().getName();
        String controllerName = pack+"."+getClass().getSimpleName()+name;

        Class<?> ctrl = null;
        try {
            ctrl = Class.forName(controllerName);
            return (Controller) ctrl.newInstance();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: You're right about artificiality of this code :) Actually, current implementation is just a monolithic `FormField` implementing those controller interfaces and keeping all logic inside. I'll show it in question edit.

Comment: PS: I think solution using names of entities will break when code is obfuscated. Maybe annotations can help?..